# Lightning Web Component to retrieve RecordId and Address fields

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to use the google maps LWC to display a map on a record page that contains basic address info. I'm having two problems; 1) Getting the record Id. 2) Getting the address info

I have (or at least I think I have) debugged the variable values using devTools and found that they are undefined. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-map
        map-markers={mapMarkers}
></lightning-map>
<lightning-record-view-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name={secObject}>
</lightning-record-view-form>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import SECURITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Securities__c';
import STREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Securities__c.Street_del__c';
import CITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Securities__c.Street_del__c';
import POSTCODE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Securities__c.Zip_Postal_Code_del__c';

export default class LightningExampleMapSingleMarker extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    /* Expose schema objects/fields to the template. */
    secObject = SECURITY_OBJECT;

    /* Load Account.Name for custom rendering */
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [STREET_FIELD, CITY_FIELD, POSTCODE_FIELD] })
    record;

    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {
                Street: STREET_FIELD,
                City: CITY_FIELD,
                State: POSTCODE_FIELD,
            },

            title: 'The White House',
            description:
                'Landmark, historic home & office of the United States president, with tours for visitors.',
        },
    ];
}
```

Comment: recordId definition seemed to be find. So if you add renderedCallback() and debug recordId it should be populated

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mean like this? 

export default class LightningExampleMapSingleMarker extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    renderedCallback() {
        recordId;
    }

Comment: ye, but you forgot `this.`
```
renderedCallback() {
console.log(this.recordId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ..its still undefined in the console

Comment: Is this is exposed component and you are adding it directly onto Lightning Record Page?

Comment: Yes thats correct for both

Comment: I found this trailhead module, I think it will contain the answers I need do dont worry for now.. I'll post an answer when i work it out

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/lwc-build-flexible-apps/single-record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISSUES:

1. You are directly assigning data to `mapMarkers` during declaration of class - you did not even get the data from wire service at this point (In fact, `getRecord` will not even be invoked at this point. It will just be declared with `undefined` data and error) .
2. `Street` should have value in `mapMarkers` and not field API name `STREET_FIELD` .
3. You do not need `lightning-record-view-form` in template as you not showing any info. `getRecord` is good enough to get data - you dont need anything else .

**SOLUTION:**

1. You should assign data to `mapMarkers` after getting data from `getRecord` service. This should be ideally wired function as you need to process the record data in Javascript .
2. Use conditional rendering in template as [lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/example) will throw error when `map-markers` is supplied undefined. And `map-markers` will not get data until `getRecord` service returns data.

Below is the example which uses `Account` object:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={mapMarkers}>
        <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers}></lightning-map>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import STREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingStreet';
import CITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCity';
import POSTCODE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingState';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Description';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track mapMarkers;

    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [ STREET_FIELD, CITY_FIELD, POSTCODE_FIELD, DESCRIPTION_FIELD, NAME_FIELD ]
    })
    fetchAcc({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.mapMarkers = [
                {
                    location: {
                        Street: data.fields.BillingStreet.value,
                        City: data.fields.BillingCity.value,
                        State: data.fields.BillingState.value
                    },

                    title: data.fields.Name.value,
                    description: data.fields.Description.value
                }
            ];
            console.log('this.mapMarkers => ', JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('ERROR => ', error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) ..can I ask why you hard code the id ? 
@api recordId = '0010K000028HCgAQAW';

Comment: Just a default - for my testing - if you dont pass the value (not loaded in record context), that value will be taken - removing it

Comment: Ah ok cool. Thanks for confirming